# sed line to change surrounding colons to dots in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I need a sed regex line that will change colons to dots that surround a variable such as from this

```
a:b:c :d: e:f
```

to this

```
a:b:c: .d. e:f
```

(**`d`** variable). I've scoured the internet for countless hours trying to find a solution... which is no easy task when Google ignores most punctuation marks. I've also search several dozen shell scripting books and PDF's, but to no avail. Although I've used single letters, each letter in this example could be full variables, e.g.

```
cat:dog:bird :rabbit: mouse:rat
```

(**`rabbit`**) or even path names:

```
/home/someone/bin:/home/someone/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin :/usr/local/bin: /usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

(**`/usr/local/bin`**).  All examples have one thing in common, a variable in the middle that is surrounded by colons that needs to be changed to period. Is this even possible with sed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you also have spaces around what you want to replace as shown here? or is your requirement to always change between 3rd and 4th colon?

Comment: Thought:  You may not find a ready made sed string on the net to achieve what you seek.  You may need (if you have not already) experiment on constructing a regular search and replace expression yourself to achieve your specific goal here. There are some good pdf, webpage and utube vids on how to construct find and replace strings.  If you do get one that does the job, then you can post your solution for others for this particular pattern recognition problem.

Comment: Why are `:b:` and `:dog:` not replaced?

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the second string that needs replacing you could use awk like:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^:|:$/,".",$2)}1' file
a:b:c .d. e:f
```

(if you want to switch leading and trailing colons in all string, use:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/^:|:$/,".",$i)}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

What you call a *variable* is not fully clear. If it is a word (alphanumeric and underscore characters only), you can use:

```
sed -E 's/(^|\s):(\w+):($|\s)/\1.\2.\3/'
```

But if it is a path, things are much more complex because a path can contain almost any character, including spaces... If you want a regular expression that works for paths you must tell us a bit more about the kind of paths you have.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the middle with 3 parts.
you can use

```
sed 's/ :\([^:]*\): / .\1. /'
```

or if you have tab

```
sed 's/\t:\([^:]*\):\t/\t.\1.\t/'
```

but variable can't have : in it